# Using Fermat's little theorem to find remainders.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

I don't understand how to use Fermat's little theorem to find remainders e.g if we are asked to find remainder of 50^50 on division by 13, what is a and what is p in the formula? What is going on?? Are we using **congruence classes** when using Fermat's little theorem? Can someone please give me a step by step explanation from the beginning, I'm  just not understanding this stuff.

Comment: $50 = 4\times 12 +2$, do you think this will help? How might you then simplify $50^{50}$? Bearing in mind that $12 = 13-1$ and $(50,13)=1$...

Comment: Finding the remainder $r$ is the same as solving $$50^{50}=r\mod13$$

Comment: Please do not reask your [prior question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/765123/242) If the answer does not suffice, ask for help in comments, and/or edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

$50^{50} = (50^{12})^4\cdot 50^2$. Now apply Fermat little theorem: $50^{12} \equiv 1 \pmod {13}$. So $(50^{12})^4 \equiv 1^4 \equiv 1 \pmod {13}$, and $50^2 \equiv 4 \pmod {13}$. So: $50^{50} \equiv 4 \pmod {13}$